# Add column/custom field in MS Project .mpp file programmatically

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I am using following code to create the .mpp file programmatically. This create a MS project file with default fields (Task Mode, Task Name, Duration...). I want to add a custom column/fields with name "MYCustom Field" in this new created file. Can any body guide me how to accomplish this.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application projectApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();

projectApplication.Visible = false;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project ProjectSheet projectApplication.Projects.Add(missing, missing, missing);

projectApplication.ActiveProject.SaveAs("test.mpp", Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjFileFormat.pjMPP, missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with mpp files only then "Add a custom field" means pick one of standard custom fields: Text1-32, Duration1-.., Date1-.., Number1-.., Flag1-.. depending on what type of your data and assign your own label to the field.

To do that you should use `Table.TableField.Add` method. Here is a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/office.vbapj.chm132642%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Table is a grid on the left in the MS Project.

You can either redefine one of standard tables Available through `Application.Tables` or create your own using `Application.TableCopy` `Application.TableApply`.

From my experience common rule about MS Project Programming: try to find dedicated object for what you need and if there is no such object - check Application.